# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 Models in My Laravel App like Employee , Salary and Title. Employee Model one to Many Relationship with both Salary and Title Models. Now I need update data using EmployeeController updateEmployee function using this function I need update some time all 3 tables tada also.
EmployeeController

```
public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id) {
    $employee = Employee::find($id);
    $title = $employee->titles()->update($request->all);
    $salary = $employee->salaries()->update($request->all);
    if(is_null($employee)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Employee not found'], 404);
    }
    $employee->update($request->all());
    
    return response($employee, 200);

}
```

and my api route is following

```
Route::put('updateEmployee/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@updateEmployee');
```

Employee Model

```
public function titles(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Title::class, 'emp_no');
}

public function salaries(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Salary::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

Salary Model

```
public function employee(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

Title Model

```
public function employee(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

but when I try update I got following error message
`Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;first_name&#039; in &#039;field list&#039; (SQL: update` titles`set`first_name`= kevin,`salary`= 90000 where`titles`.`emp_no`= 10 and`titles`.`emp_no`is not null) in file F:\2023\code\2023\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 760`

how could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way u should do is parse your fields and thats it. So in controller you can have smth like this:

```
public function store(PoseCreateRequest $request)
{
    Pose::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('pose.index');
}
```

and in folder `app/Http/Requests` create `PoseCreateRequest.php` i mean create your own name and add

```
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'your_fieldname_1' => ['required',],
            'your_fieldname_2' => ['required'],
            'captcha' => ['required', 'captcha'],
        ];
    }
```

and done, now back to controller and as usual in your `$request->all()` you have all fields, but when u make validation so your `$request->all()` contains only validate existing fields in request file. even if your request before has 10 fields, after this code u will return only `your_fieldname_1` ,`your_fieldname_1`, `captcha`

Answer (score 0):

```
The issue is that you are trying to update all columns at once by passing $request->all() to the update method, which is causing Laravel to generate an incorrect SQL query.

You should update the related records separately and specify which columns you want to update. Here's how you can fix your updateEmployee function:

public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id)
{
    $employee = Employee::find($id);

    if (is_null($employee)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Employee not found'], 404);
    }

    // Update employee information
    $employee->update([
        'first_name' => $request->input('first_name'),
        'other_employee_fields' => $request->input('other_employee_fields'),
        // Add other employee fields as needed
    ]);

    // Update related titles
    $employee->titles->update([
        'title_field' => $request->input('title_field'),
        // Add other title fields as needed
    ]);

    // Update related salaries
    $employee->salaries->update([
        'salary_field' => $request->input('salary_field'),
        // Add other salary fields as needed
    ]);

    return response($employee, 200);
}
```

Comment: only update employee table and got following error message `BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist. in file F:\2023\code\2023\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php on line 113
`

Comment: dd($employee);
Please check the relationship data for the `title` and `salary` to identify any issues or solutions.